# On average conditional min-entropy

Tags: information-theory

The average conditional min-entropy of X given Y,
$\tilde H_\infty( X | Y)$, measures, roughly speaking,
the amount of randomness that is in $X$ given as side information $Y$.

(for the formal def, https://eprint.iacr.org/2003/235)

Consider the following statement:

Let $A,B,Z$ be arbitrary random variables, let $k\in \mathbb{R}$, and let $f$ be a function 
if
$\tilde H_\infty( A, B | f(A,B), Z) \geq \tilde H_\infty( A,B | Z) - k$
then
$\tilde H_\infty( A | f(A,B), Z) \geq \tilde H_\infty( A | Z) - k$

I would like to know under which circumstances the statement above is true.
Intuitively, it seems true, in the sense, if $f(A,B)$ leaks at most $k$ bits of $A,B$ when the auxiliary info $Z$ is know, then at most $f$ leaks $k$ bits of $A$.

**A simple case :**
If $B$ is uniformly random over $\{0,1\}^l$ and $Z$ is the empty value, then, by a simple derivation that uses the chain rule of the avg. conditional min-entropy, we can prove the statement above.
In fact:

$$ \tilde H_\infty( A| f(A,B) ) \geq
\tilde H_\infty( A,B | f(A,B) )- l \geq
H_\infty( A,B ) - k -l \geq
H_\infty( A ) - k - l + l$$

What can we say when $B$ is uniformly random and $Z = g(A,B)$ for an arbitrary function?

Comment: Sorry, maybe this is just me not getting something, but how can $\tilde H_\infty$ suddenly have more than one argument? Is this the min-entropy of the set of the values together?

Comment: Think $X$ be defined as the concatenation of $A$ and $B$ for one side, and $Y$ be defined as the concatenation of $f(A,B),Z$ for the other side. Does it make sense?